# Add a knowledge base dialogflow to flutter app

Tags: flutter, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am trying to add my FQA bot to my flutter mobile app. The dialogflow intents work fine on the flutter app, but the FQA I added to my dialogflow dashboard does not work on the flutter app. However, it is working when I try it on the dashboard itself.

I am using flutter version 3.13.8 with dialogflow_grpc 0.2.9, I also used dialog_flowtter 0.3.3

Any help?